# How can I get the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) from a SharePoint user (SPUser object)?

Tags: sharepoint

Within SharePoint I have an instance of the [SPUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms456617.aspx) class.  The LoginName property is a string in the format domain\user, but in this case the domain is the netbios domain name and not the fully qualified domain name (FQDN).

I need the FQDN.  There is a SID available to me if that helps.  Do I have to do some LDAP query to get this or is there some other way to figure this out?

In the end, I really want the userPrincipalName (e.g., john.doe@corp.mycompany.com).  The part after the "@" needs to be the FQDN as another system will be querying the UPN from AD and its value needs to match my value.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the SPUser and [SPUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470715%28v=office.12%29.aspx) class I think your only option is to get it from LDAP using username.